# Ninject activation exception on publish: ILogManager

Tags: dependency-injection, social-connected

I started getting a strange error on publish in one our our dev sitecore instances that seems to be coming from some `Sitecore.Social.Client` piplines.

> Exception[1]: Ninject.ActivationException 
>   Message[1]: Error activating ILogManager
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>   1) Request for ILogManager
>
> Suggestions:
>     1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for ILogManager.
>     2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
>     3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
>     4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
>     5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
>
> Source[1](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/3102): Ninject 
>      at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request)
>      at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters)
>      at **Sitecore.Social.Client.MessagePosting.Handlers.PublishEndHandler.DoClearDbMesageCache**(EventArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) 
>   ...

We use AutoFac for DI and manually adding a registration for `ILogManager` to the AutoFac container didn't seem to resolve this issue. I decompiled the dll to see what the offending line was and it was apparently trying resolve `IlogManager` to log an exception (which wasn't logged because it threw in the catch).

```
try
  {
    using (new SiteContextSwitcher(SiteContext.GetSite("shell")))
    {
                    ItemProcessedEventArgs processedEventArgs = args as ItemProcessedEventArgs;
                    if (processedEventArgs == null || processedEventArgs.Context.Result.Operation != PublishOperation.Created && processedEventArgs.Context.Result.Operation != PublishOperation.Updated || processedEventArgs.Context.VersionToPublish == null)
                        return;
                    IMessageManager messageManager = (IMessageManager)Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get<IMessageManager>((IResolutionRoot)ExecutingContext.Current.IoC, new IParameter[0]);
                    foreach (Message message in messageManager.GetMessagesByContainer(processedEventArgs.Context.VersionToPublish.Uri.ToString()).Where<Message>((Func<Message, bool>)(message => message.PostingConfiguration is ContainerPostingConfiguration)).ToList<Message>())
                    {
                        //do message things
                    }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     //blows on this next line
    ((ILogManager) ResolutionExtensions.Get<ILogManager>((IResolutionRoot) ExecutingContext.Current.IoC, new IParameter[0])).LogMessage(ex.Message, Sitecore.Social.Infrastructure.Logging.LogLevel.Error, (object) this, ex);
  }
```

I don't want add Ninject and wire up a seperate IOC container if I can avoid it. I'm considering just disabling Sitecore Social altogether but I figured I'd see if there is a better way. I have a different site with identical configs that doesn't have this publishing issue and nothing seemed strange in showconfig.

Any ideas? I saw this [community post](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/3102) about the same issue but there is no resolution there.

**Update**

I went through and created a Pipeline override and brought my own logging in to see if I could get the original exception. Since it was failing in the `catch` clause, I figured the root exception might be more helpful. Unfortunately it just turned out to be a different Ninject Activation error.

```
//blows up here
IMessageManager messageManager = (IMessageManager)Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get<IMessageManager>((IResolutionRoot)ExecutingContext.Current.IoC, new IParameter[0]);
```

> Exception: Ninject.ActivationException Message: Error activating
>   IMessageManager No matching bindings are available, and the type is
>   not self-bindable. Activation path:   1) Request for IMessageManager

So it looks like it is not specific to `ILogManager` since the previous call to resolve `IMessageManager` also fails. More of a global problem with this `Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get<IMessageManager>` call.

Comment: Hi @Rondel, have you found any solution? I am experiencing the same issue on 8.2 update 6, couldn't find any clue (My solution is using the sitecore 8.2 default DI)

Comment: @Vincent I never figured this out unfortunately. I ended up completely disabling Sitecore Social as a workaround because we weren't using it. Your best bet may be the nuclear option and trying a clean install to see if that magically fixes the problem

Comment: I resolved this by commenting out the line `<setting name="Social.IoC.AssemblyFullName" value="Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7" />` in Sitecore.Social.config.